# Get consumerSecret through Metadata API

Tags: metadata-api

Is it possible to retrieve the consumer secret through the Metadata API for Salesforce for a connected app. It is listed as a property for the oathConfig but it always returns null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a write-only field. It is exposed so that you can set whatever value you want for the secret (e.g. for migration to a new org, or to change a compromised secret). From a design philosophy, it is considered a password, and as such, cannot be retrieved for security reasons.